# Angular2 (Typescript) can't import node module from @types

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm trying to import log4js node module into Angular2 app, but it gives

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
```

Could you guide me how to solve this issue? My app is based on [quickstart angular app](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

I've installed `@types/log4js` node package, in addition to the normal package.

I've mapped module in `systemjs.config.js` as

`'log4js':'npm:@types/log4js/index.d.ts'` inside map section,

adding it to packages section changes nothing

`'log4js': { main: 'index.d.ts', defaultExtension: 'ts' }`

In my component, I use

```
import * as logger from "log4js";
let foo = logger.getDefaultLogger();
```

`tsc --traceResolution` gives the follwoing output

```
======== Type reference directive 'log4js' was successfully resolved to '/home/xxx/xxx/parent-folder/node_modules/@types/log4js/index.d.ts', primary: true. ========
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger ?
 1. Install by running `npm install --save angular2-logger`
 2. Configure it in the `systemjs.config.js`
 3. Add it in the `providers` array of your module
 4. Add it in every component you want to use it

More details in -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-logger

Comment: No,I'm using log4js, and the issue is somehow linked to incorrect module resolution.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, but it seems that other devs run into problems and used the packages that i suggested. If you don't have very specific reason not to use it i would give it a try, cause their installation process seems to be quite simple and you are using the `quickstart angular app`. I think it will be much easier for you :)